# IPhone: changing signature on app update

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, signature

I need an answer to the following question:

I want to develop an iOS app in two phases.

1) The app doesn't need a defined app ID so I sign it with my general purpose developer signature

2) I need to add to my app Push Notifications so I need to define a specifid app id and I have to sign the updated binary with a specific app signature.

The question (may be naive):

What happens to already installed old versions?
They will update normally dispite of different signature?

To be honest I think so since I think that the bundle id is what makes the difference and with a defined bundle id (that in phase 2 will be rhe same of app id) all the apps will be updated even if signed with different signatures.

Can you confirm this?

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: how do you mean _what happens to already installed old versions?_? you were not able to publish your application in the AppStore without an App ID, because the unique App ID is needed for the distribution provision profiles, as far as I know.

Comment: Yes I just want to change the signature for the update.
The Bundle ID is fixed

Comment: if you don't change the `Application ID`, you should not worry about anything. what kind of signature are you talking about exactly?

Comment: The first one should be the "wildcard" signature. The second one the specific signature created for the specific Bundle ID to support Push Notifications

Comment: I still don't understand how you mean _signature_ or _specific signature_. perhaps you would mean the _Certificate_ or _Provision Profiles_ or _Distribution Profile_ or the _App ID_ or what? could you use the common terminology instead of own language, please?

Comment: I call "signature" the item you can find in the "Build Settings"->"Code Sign Identity"->"Distribution". Here you can use a "wildcard" identity (for all your apps that don't need a specific certificate) or a "specific" identity created for the specific "Bundle identifier" (inside your app's info.plist) when you need to support Push Notifications. The question is: Can I use first the wildcard identity then the specific identity?

Comment: you **cannot** use any `App ID` with asterisk `*` for the following services: `In-App Purchase`, `Game Center` or `Push Notification`. **[read this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12173283/ios-provisioning-portal-app-id/12174207#12174207)** for the further. if you have question, feel free to ask.

Comment: Yes I know but here the question is still different. I want to publish an app without Push Notifications, so I use my wildcard identity to publish it. Then, after 1 year, I want to add Push Notifications, so App ID is the same but I cannot use the wildcard identity for the reason you said; so I create a new identity with the fully qualified App ID. The question is: everything will work? Old apps will receive the update notification? I think so but I wish someone to confirm this. Thanks

Comment: probably, it will be a completely new application with a completely new `App ID` like a totally other application. because the `App ID` defines the application, it can identify the application, you cannot change the `App ID` on the air without pain. some relevant sections form the Apple's page: _If you are just starting development, you can use a generic app ID that Xcode provides for you. However, if you use certain technologies, you may need an explicit app ID._ and _You cannot change an app ID after you register it._ it seems you should have thought it in time.

Comment: have you made an application lifecycle plan? in that document have you described the `Push Notification` as a possible future service in you app? if yes, why haven't you done the preparation for it in time? if no, why haven't made lifecycle plan? this is the first step of the development before you write any line of code. :(

Comment: My friend you still don't understand the question. The App ID is FIXED, is the identity that changes. Push Notification is an app's optional so if the client doesn't want it (since it's not free) I don't waste my time to create certificates, provisioning profiles, etc.

Comment: okay, I explain you shorty again: **1. you need an explicit and unique** `App ID` without asterisk for the `Push Notification` service. the generic `App ID` is definitely not usable. **2. if you change** the `App ID` anytime for any reason it will be a new application from then in the AppStore. (you will have to change the provision profiles as well for the new `App ID`). is it answer to your question finally?

Comment: No my friend, the App ID is always fixed. Ok let's stop this or we move this into a chat. TY

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16247/discussion-between-holex-and-oscar-peli)

Answer (score 2):

When you create an app in iTunes Connect - you get a unique Apple ID. This is what is unique on the app store.

You also create it with a Bundle ID. The bundle ID is the unique identifier for iOS.

You can't change your Bundle ID once you have associated it with an app, but you can build your app using the developer wildcard id and then later on use another bundle id for the app store.

Have a read of: https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/bundles/howto.action

Comment: No my question is different:

The Bundle ID will not change, is the signature that will change.

In the phase 1) I will use my wildcard signature that is valid for all my apps.

In phase 2) I will use a specific signature built on the (fixed) 
app's bundle ID.

Is this possible?

Thanks