# iOS Provisioning Portal – App ID

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase, provisioning, app-id

I have an app in the App Store, recently updated. I added an In-App Purchase in it. App ID created in iOS Provisioning Portal says that In-App Purchases is not available:
[image]

However, it works just fine... So my question is what is App ID and where I need it?

Comment: You submitted app to app store After that u are trying to add in app purchase  Is this is your scenario

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for these services you have to create a unique `AppID`. the `AppID` which contains the asterisk `*` **is not unique** `AppID`.

example for the **unique** `AppID`:

## ABCDEFGHIJK.com.applicationid.veryunique

---

the following IDs **cannot use** the relevant services because **they are not unique** IDs *(so the services are unavailable for you for your similar IDs with asterisk)*:

**ABCDEFGHIJK.com.applicationid.*** or

**ABCDEFGHIJK.com.*** or

**ABCDEFGHIJK.***

---

see the live picture here, and spot the asterisk `*` in the first `AppID` and you are seeing the most of the services are unavailable.

the second one **does not contains** any asterisk and all of the services are available for it.

[image]

I hope this simple explanation is good enough to solve your problem.

Comment: But, even with unavailable In-App Purchases here, they are still working good at the App Store :) Yes, my App ID is with this asterisk.

Comment: then, you have to create another `AppID` **without** asterisk, as I've suggested in the first part of my answer, you can see a good example for the unique ID without asterisk.

Answer (score 1):

After Submitting App to app store without in-App purchase 
You can not add in app purchase to that app This is a issue with app id not your application

You need to create a new app id then submit app with in app purchase